# Are there examples of cells with more than one nucleus?

Tags: dna, chromosome

I've always wondered why cells have only one nucleus, as having multiple would seemingly prevent mutation. Are there examples of organisms with multiple nucleuses? If not, is there a reason?

Comment: From a certain standpoint, your own cells have more than one nucleus, in the sense that they contain [mitochondria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrion).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Are there examples of cells with more than one nucleus?

Yes, they are called [Multinucleate cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinucleate). There are two types of multinucleated cells

- Syncytia
- Coenocytes

I highly recommend having a look at [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/64429/is-it-correct-to-use-the-terms-multinucleate-and-syncitia-interchangeably/64439#64439) for the definitions.

Examples of Syncytia include

- Osteoclasts
- Skeletal muscle fibers (thanks @kmm)

Examples of Coenocytes include

- Codium (Thanks @GerardoFurtado; see picture below)
- Blastoderms early in the development of a fruit fly

> Are there examples of organisms with multiple nucleuses?

Side note: The plural of *nucleus* is *nuclei*

In many fungi, during sexual reproduction, a fusion of cytoplasm happen early in the mycelium but a fusion of the nucleus happens only very late (just before sporulation). This is a type of Coenocytic mycelium. In these species, non-negligible fractions of their cells are multinucleated.

There are endosymbiotic and endoparasitic eukaryotes in other eukaryotes that would result in a cell containing several nuclei but that would not count I would guess as the nuclei belong to different species.

---

Picture of Codium. The entire algea is a single multinucleated cell.

[image]

Comment: *"I doubt there are species where all cells are constantly multinucleated"*..  except for the gamete phase, that's exactly the situation for several species of algae and protozoa, in which all cells are always multinucleated (+1 though).

Comment: Also, the way you created your list may not be very didactic to a layman: **all** multinucleate cells are either a syncytium or a coenocyte. There is no other category. However, in your list, it seems that there is more... For instance, skeletal muscle cells are syncytia. have a look at my answer here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/64439/24284 . I'm seeing that the mistake is from the Wikipedia page you shared: osteoclasts are syncytia.

Answer (score 11):

There is a branch of life called the Diplomonads, most of which have two nuclei. They are single cell organisms and an early offshoot of the eukaryotic linage. A good example is Giardia lamblia.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomonad
Giardia lamblia

Answer (score 8):

According to this article [The hairy beast with seven fuzzy sexes](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn20191-zoologger-the-hairy-beast-with-seven-fuzzy-sexes/)

*Tetrahymena thermophila* has two: a large macronucleus and a small micronucleus. The macronucleus controls the everyday functions of the cell, while the micronucleus deals with its complicated sex life. In fact this is true for all [ciliates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciliate).

Answer (score 4):

When a "slime mold" enters the "plasmodium" phase n cells merge together to form one cell with n nuclei.  This means plasmodiums can have thousands or tens of thousands of nuclei...

Answer (score 1):

Skeletal muscles (striated) are multi-nucleated-have more than one nucleus per cell as they are formed as a result of the fusion of myoblasts.

Reference-   Skeletal Muscle: Form and Function (2006)
By Brian R. MacIntosh, Phillip F. Gardiner, Alan J. McComas